# Matplotlib unaligned values and names of graphs

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, web

Good day! I am making a django app that would plot graphs from a text document. In the text document data is aligned this way:

```
name 10
name_2 20
name_3 100
typeofthegrah
```

I just split everything by spaces and put in 2 lists (names and values), then I just do `plt.bar(names, values)` and get something like this [image: graphs]

```
name1 189
name2 149 
name3 23
name4 82
name5 245
name6 90
column
```

I tried sorting them with `zip` but it didn't work. It works perfectly if I plot it as a pie chart but linear and bar graphs are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values to plot are being read in as strings which is why the y-axis is broken. Try casting the values as int or float by using something like:

```
values = [float(x) for x in values]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just implemented a function that checks if some string can be converted to float but I didn't actually make a conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Here's Your Solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6"])
y = np.array([189, 149, 23, 82, 245, 90])

plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```